# How do I connect to my broadband automatically when I startup?

Tags: 11.04, broadband

Can someone tell me how to set up ubuntu to connect to my broadband hub automatically when I start my computer, as it is I have to connect manually each time. Thanks. 
I'm using version 11.04

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection wifi or Ethernet? The network manager by the clock on the top right bar should handle connections.

Click the icon (looks like radar) and go to edit connections. Then on the network connections window that pops up, find your connection (Wired/Ethernet - Wireless/Wifi etc) and once highlighted, click edit. Then tick the connect automatically box on the edit window and save.